# Index Aliases and zero downtime with Spring data Elastisearch

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using version 4.2.2 of spring-data-elasticsearch in my project.
We need to reindex some data every day, so we are using aliases. I have seen that there is a way to **atomically** remove an index from an alias and to include a new one.
Link: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index-aliases.html

My question is if that feature is supported and included as part of version 4.2.2 of spring-data-elasticsearch, at IndexOperations class level.

**EDIT**

Using AliasActions to remove an existing index (the old one) and to add an alias to the new index I am getting this exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.alias.IndicesAliasesRequest$AliasActions org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.alias.IndicesAliasesRequest$AliasActions.isHidden(java.lang.Boolean)'

var aliasActions = new AliasActions()
      .add(new AliasAction.RemoveIndex(AliasActionParameters.builder()
          .withIndices(oldIndexName).build()))
      .add(new AliasAction.Add(
          AliasActionParameters.builder().withIndices(newIndexName)
              .withAliases(indexOps.getIndexCoordinates().getIndexNames()).build()));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the `IndexOperations.alias(AliasActions aliasActions)` method for that (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/4.2.2/api/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/IndexOperations.html#alias-org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.index.AliasActions-).

An `AliasAction`can be a add, remove or removeindex, and these AliasActions are sent to ES in one operation and executed there atomically.

Comment: Thanks. I've used that method. I updated the question. I am getting an exception trying to add the alias to the new index. If I remove the Add AliasAction from the request, the RemoveIndex works fine.

Comment: The problem was a version mismatch. I was using 7.6.2 client libs and my cluster is on 7.8.0. Updating client libs to 7.8.0 fixed the issue.